# How to integrate QT internationalization to CMake?

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qt4, cmake

Greetings all,

I am trying to use QT internationalization with CMake.
I have configured my cmake file as follows :

```
#Internalization - this should generate core_jp.ts ?
SET(rinzo_core_TRANSLATIONS
   i18n/core_jp.ts
   )

#these are my source files in the project
SET(FILES_TO_TRANSLATE
   ${rinzo_core_srcs} 
   ${rinzo_core_moh_srcs}
 )

QT4_CREATE_TRANSLATION(QM_FILES ${FILES_TO_TRANSLATE} ${rinzo_core_TRANSLATIONS})
QT4_ADD_TRANSLATION(QM ${rinzo_core_TRANSLATIONS})
```

But it doesnt genereate any TS nor QM files.

My questions -

1.Does Cmake(by using QT tools) generate TS files automatically extracting "tr()" methods from the source ? (that means I dont have to create any TS file and above i18n/core_jp.ts will be genereated automatically)

2.What exacly are QM files ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Translation binary files (*.qm) according to http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Build_Qt4_Software

Answer (score 8):

In [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:FindQt4) documentation see `QT4_CREATE_TRANSLATION` and `QT4_ADD_TRANSLATION` macros.

So you should do the followings:

```
SET(Lang_files
  example.ts
)
...
QT4_CREATE_TRANSLATION(LangSrcs ${Lang_files})
...
ADD_EXECUTABLE(project_name ... others sources ... ${LangSrcs})
```

Comment: When I do that I get: CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:44 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    /home/panzi/software/qjoypad/qjoypad/build-locale/qjoypad_de.qm

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx

Answer (score 4):

Translation binary files (*.qm) according to http://itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Build_Qt4_Software

Also from the bottom of that website

```
Usage - Updating the .ts files
```

> When you want it to process all your
>   source files (looking for new texts to
>   translate), configure cmake to turn on
>   UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS, and then make
>   your project. CMake will modify your
>   .ts files in your SOURCE folders in
>   addition to generating the .qm files.
>   WARNING: Be aware that CMake will be updating the source .ts files, which means that if > you do a make clean, it will DELETE your source .ts files!!! So it would be a good idea > to switch off UPDATE_TRANSLATIONS as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks,I followed the same procedure but nothing generated!

Answer (score 4):

My solution relies on manually invoked lupdate and lrelease tools via add_custom_target, so the generated files are not removed on make clean and put into the source directory.

I defined a function that scans provided directory, generates/updates ts files, and compiles them into qm files in the same directory, so they can be added to the app via .qrc file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(l10n LANGUAGES CXX)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core LinguistTools REQUIRED)

# genearats ts and qm file searching recursively SRC_DIR
function(generate_translations CUSTOM_TARGET TS_DIR TS_FILES SRC_DIR)
    set(UPADTE_TS_TARGET_NAME ${CUSTOM_TARGET}_ts)
    set(UPADTE_QM_TARGET_NAME ${CUSTOM_TARGET}_qm)

    add_custom_target(${UPADTE_TS_TARGET_NAME}
        COMMAND ${Qt5_LUPDATE_EXECUTABLE} -recursive ${SRC_DIR} -ts ${TS_FILES}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TS_DIR})

    add_custom_target(${UPADTE_QM_TARGET_NAME}
        COMMAND ${Qt5_LRELEASE_EXECUTABLE} ${TS_FILES}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TS_DIR})

    add_dependencies(${UPADTE_QM_TARGET_NAME} ${UPADTE_TS_TARGET_NAME} )
    add_dependencies(${CUSTOM_TARGET} ${UPADTE_QM_TARGET_NAME})
endfunction()

add_executable(l10n main.cxx)

target_link_libraries(l10n Qt5::Core)

set(MY_TS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/translate)
set(MY_TS_FILES foo_en.ts foo_en.ts)
set(MY_SOURCE_LOOKUP_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

generate_translations(l10n "${MY_TS_DIR}" "${MY_TS_FILES}" "${MY_SOURCE_LOOKUP_DIR}")
```

Comment: just curious... are you still using Qt 3.5 ? :)

Answer (score 0):

can you use lupdate.exe, linguist.exe and lrelease.exe from qt/[qt_version]/[msvc|mingw|...]/bin/ ?

you can use it like that:

```
Usage:
    lupdate [options] [project-file]
    lupdate [options] [source-file|path]... -ts ts-files
Options:
    -help  Display this information and exit.
    -noobsolete
           Drop all obsolete strings.
    -extensions [,]...
           Process files with the given extensions only.
           The extension list must be separated with commas, not with whitespace.
           Default: 'ui,c,c++,cc,cpp,cxx,ch,h,h++,hh,hpp,hxx'.
    -pluralonly
           Only include plural form messages.
    -silent
           Do not explain what is being done.
    -version
           Display the version of lupdate and exit
```

so, [source-file|path] - is you option, like i think.
try to call it with list of source files names.